# Update Mediawiki user password using database

Tags: mediawiki

How to modify MediaWiki(v 1.15) user password without using the maintenance script, direct to database.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I did it... manually inserting in database

```
"UPDATE wikiuser SET user_password=md5(CONCAT('67','-',MD5('pass'))) WHERE user_id = 15"
```

Answer (score 3):

There's a maintenance script to do that:

`php maintenance/changePassword.php --user=USER --password=PASSWORD`

Comment: Thanks, but i have to do that with out manitenance script I did it manually inserting in database 
"UPDATE `wikiuser` SET `user_password`=md5(CONCAT('67','-',MD5('pass'))) WHERE `user_id` = 15"